What should be the grain orientation of the top and tail blocks when gluing to the sides of an acoustic guitar?
What way up should the inside top and tail blocks be glued to the sides of an acoustic guitar?
Below are 6 diagrams to illustrate the possible directions I could place a top block in relation to the guitar sides looking down inside a guitar as if the top plate had been removed.
The arrow direction indicate the grain direction
which one out of the 6 examples is the correct orientation?







P.S. I have also heard the top block being referred to either the heel or neck block as well.
I Also plan to do a dove tail joint to attach the guitar neck so this might also influence the orientation too

My interpretation of the comment in this thread is that diagram no 5 is the correct orientation https://www.mandolincafe.com/forum/threads/117753-Confirming-head-block-grain-direction " Guitar head blocks are normally cut so that the grain direction matches the sides. That means the block and the sides move in similar ways and end grain is presented to the neck tenon (dovetail, if there is a dovetail) "

Having made several violins previously, standard methodology is more like orientation 1, with growth rings visible across the top the block, running from L-R. Guitar makers may have other preferences that I'm not aware of, so I'm willing to hear their arguments for and against.
Particularly if you plan to cut a dovetail, using diagram 1, orient the grain direction top-to-bottom so that you can pare the sides of the dovetail socket downwards neatly with your chisel. I oriented a head block "upside-down" once and the chisel would grab at the grain and dig into the sides rather than shave the insides of the joint. It's a matter of going "with the grain" not just "in the direction of the grain".
Orientation 5 (and its counterpart) have end-grain of the block) glued against the sides. This won't hold well at all, even if you plant to lock the side timbers inside the neck-block junction.
Good luck with your project.

It might be my diagram but my intention in fig. 1 is that the end grain would be touching the guitar top. My terminology matches this https://theverybasic.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/designer_wood_cutting_boards_grain_explain_log.jpg If gluing end grain is a really no-no, then I may be limited to fig. 3 due to the dimensions of the blank block that has been supplied. But feel this would create a weak dovetail socket that would be pulling at the ring layers

End blocks get glued somewhere eventually, but gluing end grain to the sides is not preferable. The longitudinal fibres of the sides will glue to the longitudinal fibres of the block much betther than the end grain will. The block doesn't hold the face and back together as much as the kerfing that lines the sides.

So you're saying gluing the block/tail end grain to the top and back isn't a major issue as long as the sides are glued to the face grain or edge grain?

Yes to your latest post: Blocks don't hold the face and back on with any great amount of "stick" (sorry, can't think of the right word there), they hold the sides in place and provide sufficient bulk or volume to support the dovetail joint of the neck, and endpin or tail piece etc. (thinking of a cello spike here). The kerfing or lining is all longitudinal grain around the inside edge of the sides and top/back of guitar, so much larger surface area than blocks can provide.
